# How to loop string inputs that break/end only when "#" is input on a single line?

Tags: python, string, loops, input, infinite

Basically, I want to create a loop that will continue getting string inputs from users until the user types only a "#" on a line.

I am coming from C++ so I am a bit lost in this Python project I have in mind.

Comment: How would you do it in C++? The process is fairly similar I bet.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
last_input = ''
while (last_input != '#'):
   last_input = input()
```

You'll probably want to do something else with the data, but this will keep asking until the user provides just `#`

And if you want to save all the inputs:

```
last_input = ''
all_input = [] # list to catch user input
while (last_input != '#'):
   last_input = input()
   all_input.append(last_input)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    s = input()
    if s == "#":
        break
```